# Multiple click events for the same element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have multiple click events for the same element? I have tried to simply have it like so:

```
$('#templates').click(function(e) {
            do something..
        });

$('#templates').click(function(e) {
            do something else also..
        });
```

Yet only the second event fires. I cannot find any decent answers explaining how to do this for a singular element in an on-click?

**Note**: the first click event calls server-side and loads a new PHP template (this may have an effect on what I can use in the second call I guess, as individually both clicks work but the server call does not work if I try a second click for the same element)

Comment: "the first click event calls server-side and loads a new PHP template" sounds curious. What do you mean by that? Multiple listeners can listen to the same event, but the order in which they run is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#templates').click(function(e) {
        functionOne();
        functionTwo();
});

function functionOne(){

}

function functionTwo(){

}
```

perhaps?

Comment: @user1394965 The same behaviour? There is no explanation was to why only the 2nd function here would be called. I would suggest posting more of your code

Comment: That's impossible, there must be code running interrupting what's going on, please supply more details.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DqSSd/

As you can see it should work well.

So please provide more information, and it would be better, if you provide JS fiddle as well.

Because so far the problem might be in:

- second event is fired before first event returns the result
- first event returns error from the server
- some of events contains syntax error
- etc

You may check something of those with investigation of NET calls to server (with Firebug or Chrome Developer toolbar).

Also for testing purposes you can type in console `$('#templates').data("events")`, so you will be able to see all events and handlers for particular element.